# Does "Speak with Dead" work with (well preserved) skeletons?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, npc, bard

The spell *Speak with Dead* says that we can talk with a **dead corpse**.

Does that mean it only works with bodies of people who were recently killed? A body that was not yet completely rotten?

I was hoping that a bard NPC would be able to talk with a long dead dwarf who would give some information about his life. Some precisions that the bard is looking for. Obviously, I can just make it work (I'm the DM, after all,) but I am wondering whether the spell is really *that* limited or not.

P.S. That skeleton has never been an undead. The dwarf just decomposed to a skeleton over the years. We're good on that end.

Comment: Related: [If a skeleton learns a language, can it speak it?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/67863)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Yes, it works with skeletons

Per [this answer to another question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/208783), Wizards of the Coast has published material that explicitly supports this use:

> There is offical adventure content in *Waterdeep: Dungeon of the Mad Mage* p. 40/41 that provides evidence:
>
> > Splayed across a broken stone bench in the middle of the room are the skeletal remains of a tiefling clad in rotted leather armor.[...]
> > Casting a *speak with dead* spell **on the skeleton** reveals that the tiefling, Savir, was a monk who fell prey to a cloaker.

Comment: I did not mention it in my other answer, so just as a comment: this is not even the only instance of skeleton heads talking under *speak with dead* in that adventure, there are several others too.

Comment: +1 great find and supporting your answer with the literature, but I think there needs to be some room for DMs to wrestle with this as the point mentioned by Tashio about "having a mouth" is still important. Maybe a jaw bone is enough... n'est-ce pas? :)

Answer (score 13):

Corpse is the one aspect you need to consider, the other is.

> The corpse must still have a mouth....

A skeleton skull is basically the head bone structure + a jawbone. Whether that is sufficient to constitute a mouth is up to you.

Dictionary defines corpse as the remains of a body. It does not define the state of the body. So the skeletal remains couple be interpreted as a corpse. The jawbone while creating the shape of a mouth is not a mouth, and would therefore limit the spell.

Comment: Yeah, at the same time a Litch can *perfectly* talk and after years may just be a jawbone too...

Comment: A lich is created with a very powerful spell and often maintained by the same level of spells as needed. A big difference. End of the day, DM's call. I've just tried to break it down into components to see limitations as requested but it's still vague in many aspects. D&D is not an anatomy definition book.

Comment: the only problem is that skeleton's can't speak "**Languages** understands all languages it knew in life but can’t speak"

Answer (score 8):

There are a few *corpse* references we can look at that might help you make an informed decision.

First is the *Animate Dead* spell, PHB pg.212;

> Choose a *pile of bones or a corpse of a Medium or Small humanoid* within range. [...] The 
>   target becomes a skeleton if you chose bones or a zombie if you chose a corpse.

In this case, a pile of bones does not qualify as a corpse for the purpose of reanimation and the two terms are not interchangeable.

Next is the *Create Undead* spell (PHB, pg.229) which uses the *corpses* of humanoids to create ghouls, ghasts, wights, or mummies. Each of which is generally depicted as being more than just a pile of bones. Since it doesn't say that a pile of bones (or skeleton) can be used to create these creatures, we can infer that once again just the bones don't qualfy as a corpse.

**As such I would conclude that the *Speak with Dead* spell cannot be used on a skeleton.** But hey, if you want it to work than as the DM you have the power to make it work.

Comment: I would anyway argue this is missing 1 part of the equation because I would dissaggree with: pile of bones == skeleton. While a Skeleton can be classified as a pile of bones, the pile of bones isn't neccesarily a skellton.

Comment: Pile of bones implies strongly "disarticulated"... corpse is almost assuredly articulated.